# Threading -> difference in using and not using ThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading

1. Is there a conceivable advantage or disadvantage on below?
2. Should I prefer one over the other?

Method to execute.

```
private void _archiveData()
{
    while(_isActive)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

not using `ThreadStart`

```
System.Threading.Thread _archiveThread = new System.Threading.Thread(_archiveData);
_archiveThread.Start();
```

using `ThreadStart`

```
System.Threading.ThreadStart _archiveThreadStart = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(_archiveData);
System.Threading.Thread _archiveThread = new System.Threading.Thread(_archiveThreadStart);
_archiveThread.Start();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is zero difference. The compiler automatically creates the `ThreadStart` delegate object for you in the first example. So it winds up being just like the second example.

I prefer the former, because it's more concise. I use delegate type inference wherever possible, which is nearly all of the time a delegate is involved.

Comment: Thanks. That is a brief and nice explanation. Cheers!